# Invalidating and ImageView outside of the MainActivity thread

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, invalidation, ui-thread

My MainActivity's contentView/View can be refresh by simply using invalidate() anywhere after calling:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

But if I were to call a Dialog in my item select:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menu_tools:
        showDialog();
        return true;
            ...
```

Doing this does not refresh the ImageView inside the Dialog:

```
public class ToolSettingsDialog extends Dialog {
                ...
private void updatePreview() {
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.widthImageView);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    bitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);

    Drawing d = null;
    d = box.getDrawing();
    s.draw(paint, canvas);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    image.invalidate();     
}
```

I've been looking all around and I can't seem to understand how to invalidate in different thread than the UI one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dialogs` are drawn on the `UI thread`, similarly to all other UI operations on Android. So that probably isn't your problem.

Also, you cannot do UI operations off the UI thread. You would have to perform the `invalidate()` on the UI thread, using something like `View.postInvalidate()` or `Activity.runOnUIThread()`.

Comment: Would it be possible to expand as to how runOnUiThread() should be used in my Dialog Class?

Comment: @Androidus I updated my answer. You can try `image.postInvalidate()`.